# Dart Exception has occurred. _CastError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' in type cast) Error

Tags: json, flutter, oop, dart, io

My goal is to convert my json file to the object list. But it constantly fails. What is the solution for my error?My goal is to store data over json file in a desktop application with Dart.

```
    class Tablo {
      final String tId;
      final String tobloIsim;
    
      Tablo(this.tId, this.tobloIsim);
    
      factory Tablo.fromJson(dynamic json) {
        return Tablo(json['id'], json['projeAdi']); //Error line
      }
    
      Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
            'id': tId,
            'projeAdi': tobloIsim,
          };
    }



    //The function from which this error occurs

    removeJson(Tablo silinecekTablo) {
      String cont = File("tablolar.json").readAsStringSync();
      List<dynamic> l = jsonDecode(cont);
      List<dynamic> liste = List<dynamic>.from(l.map((e) => Tablo.fromJson(cont)));
      print("Tam Liste : " + liste.toString());
    
      for (int i = 0; i < liste.length; i++) {
        if (liste[i] == silinecekTablo) {
          liste.remove(liste[i]);
        }
      }
    
      
      List<dynamic> silinmisListe = liste;
      String yeniTablo = jsonEncode(silinmisListe);
      File file = new File("tablolar.json");
    
      file.writeAsStringSync(yeniTablo);
      print("Silindi" + silinmisListe.toString());

}
```

Comment: Not seeing any line with a typecast.  Can you show (and highlight) the error line?

Comment: Can you share your tablolar.json file too?

Answer (score 0):

In you json file. Is "id" a int type? like

```
{
"id": 0 ,
"projeAdi":"some string"
}
```

it is different from

```
{
"id": "0" ,
"projeAdi":"some string"
}
```

If it is the first one, you need change

```
  final String tId;
```

to

```
  final int tId;
```